# How do I define custom renderers for default Markdown elements using markdoc.io?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, markdown, markdoc

The [React documentation](https://markdoc.io/docs/examples/react) on [markdoc.io](https://markdoc.io/) explains how to use the custom `Callout` and it works really well :)

If I transform it like this:

```
  Markdoc.transform(node, {
    tags: {
      callout: {
        render: "Callout",
      },
    },
  });
```

and render it like this:

```
 Markdoc.renderers.react(props.content, React, {
    components: {
      Callout: Callout,
    },
  });
```

If write

```
{% callout %}
Attention, over here!
{% /callout %}
```

It works.

The problem is that, I'm trying to use the exact same concept but write

```
# This is a title
```

I cannot make it to render my custom React component. It just always renders an `h1` HTML tag.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To override the behavior of a built-in document node, you need to [define a custom node schema](https://markdoc.io/docs/nodes).

This is an example that demonstrates how to make a heading render with a React component called Heading:

```
 Markdoc.transform(doc, {
  nodes: {
    heading: {
      render: 'Heading',
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Indeed it works. For reference. This "Heading" is a component name, so it has to exist in the `components` object passed to `Markdoc.renderers.react`